# Python unites - gathering multiple @patch decorators within another decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking, python-decorators

I'm writing an internal unit tests framework which involves mocking multiple functions/classes.
@patch seems to be working great for my needs, but as there are many tests that will require to patch many different classes/functions, I'm looking to avoid writing multiple @patch before every test and maybe encapsulate them all into another decorator.
To better illustrate my needs:

current state:

```
@patch('p.A', mockedA)
@patch('p.B', mockedB)
.
.
@patch('p.N', mockedN)
def test_this()
```

desired state:

```
@patch_all
def test_this()
```

Is it possible to implement something like this?, so far I wasn't able to as @patch requires to be followed either def or another @.

**EDIT 2:**
I've tried Michele's suggestion, but the test is no longer being identified as a test:
After adding functools.wraps to the patch_all decorator, it worked.

```
def patch_all(f):
@patch('p.A', moduleA.classA.methodA)
@patch('p.B', moduleB.classB.methodB)
.
.
@patch('p.N', moduleN.classN.methodN)
wraps(f)
def functor(*args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
return functor


class TestWrapper(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch_all
    def my_test(self):
        my test goes here...
```

With the @patch_all decorator this is what I get:

```
nosetests Tester.py --nocapture 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

If I remove it:

```
$ nosetests Tester.py --nocapture 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 7.692s

OK
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your test name must start bu `test_` otherwise the runner doesn't recognize it

Comment: Doesn't work either. Though,  I believe if that was a must, it wouldn't have ran when I remove the decorator.

Comment: Ok,  it depend from the runner. I need some time to look at it.  Maybe use `@wrap` decorator should fix it. But I cannot try it now,  i'm using a phone. I'll can try it later in the day.

Comment: You're right! i've added the functools.wraps and no it works.

Comment: I'll fix my answer later

Comment: I've fixed it... you can up vote it now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`patch` decorator like all decorators is just a function that take a function and return a function (**[EDIT]** in the original version I forgot `@functools.wraps(f)` to make a correct test decorator, thanks to @MenyIssakov to let me know that my answer was wrong). You can define your own `patch_all` decorator like

```
def patch_all(f):
    @patch('p.A', argsA)
    @patch('p.B', argsB)
    .
    .
    @patch('p.N', argsN)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def functor(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return functor
```

Now you can use `@patch_all` decorator in your tests like:

```
@patch_all
def test_all(mockN, ..., mockB, mockA):
    my beautiful test
```

You can go over this and define your own decorator that take a list of tuple to pass to the patch calls.

However i think that is not a good idea: test should be simple and mocking should be explicit to make clear the aim of the test. If you must patch a lot of objects/methods/functions in a lot of tests functions consider to [apply the decorator to the class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#test-prefix) instead of the single methods to write it just one time for all test methods.

Comment: Hi Michele,
I've tried your example which I did something similar before. my issue after using this method is that the test is no longer being identified as a unit test (I'm using nose).
Once I remove the patch_all annotation and run the nosetests tests.py It attempts to run my test, if I put back the patch_all annotation, i get the message that it ran 0 tests.